# Display value in modal text box using PHP & Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I am trying to display values from SQL Database onto a textbox using PHP and JQuery. The values are getting retrieved but does not display onto the textbox. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

require 'UpdateTimerSQL.php';

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>LiveData</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
 <body>

<div class="container">
<h2>Ajax</h2>
<p>Update Timer</p>
<table class="table">
<?php
    $table = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM Timers');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ 
      ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
            <th>Timer_1</th>
            <td data-target="Timer_1"><?php echo $row['Timer_1']; ?></td>
              <th> 
            <a href="#" data-role="update" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Update</a> 
             </th> 
        </tr>
     <?php
          } 
     ?>
    </table>

    <div class="container">


  <div class="text-center"></div>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Neutral Timer 1</label>
          <input type="hidden" id="ids" class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="Timer_1" class="form-control">

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=update]', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //this(a tag)->tr(id)->td(data attr)->text
    var Timer_1=  $(this).closest('tr[id=' + id + ']').find("td[data-target='Timer_1']").text();
    //putting value in input box
    $('#Timer_1').val(Timer_1);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });
```

EDIT:
I am able to show the values on the text field, thanks to the user who answered it here. But I am not able to update mySQL table when I change the textbox values after clicking on "#save". What am I doing wrong here?

```
 //onclick of update button
    $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
    //getting value of input box

    var ids = $(this).closest(".modal-body").find("#ids").val();
    var Timer_1= $(this).closest(".modal-body").find("#Timer_1").val();


    $.ajax({
        url : 'UpdateTimerSQL.php',
        method : 'POST' ,
        data : {Timer_1: Timer_1, ids: ids},
        success : function(response){
            $("table").find("tr[id='" + ids + "']").find("td[data-target='Timer_1']").text(Timer_1);

        }
      });

  });
```

UpdateTimerSQL.php

```
<?php
  $connection = mysqli_connect(...........);

  if(isset($_POST['ID'])){
  $Timer_1= $_POST['Timer_1'];
  $ids = $_POST['ID'];

   $result = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE Timers SET
   Timer_1='$Timer_1' WHERE ID ='$ids'");
   if($result){
    echo 'data updated';
   }

   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Fix your HTML layout, that may make things work properly. Badly formed HTML will often make the more complicated layouts not work

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you. Sorry for that. But the main problem exists under <script> tag. I am still not sure why the value is not displaying.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your table structure is invalid .Also, your `Timer_1` was not able to find the text needed thats the reason it was not working .

Your **php** code should look like below :

```
 <table class="table">
<?php
    $table = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM Timers');
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ 
      ?>
        <tr id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
            <th>Timer 1</th>
            <td data-target="Timer_1">
                <?php echo $row['Timer_1']; ?>
            </td>
              <th> 
            <a href="#" data-role="update" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">Update</a> 
             </th> 
        </tr>
     <?php
          } 
     ?>
    </table>
```

Here is **demo** code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=update]', function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    //this(a tag)->tr(id)->td(data attr)->text
    var Timer_1 = $(this).closest('tr[id=' + id + ']').find("td[data-target='Timer_1']").text();
    //putting value in input box
    $("#ids").val(id)
    $('#Timer_1').val(Timer_1);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });

  //onclick of update button
  $(document).on('click', '#save', function() {
    //getting value of input box
    var input_val = $(this).closest(".modal-body").find("#Timer_1").val();
    //getting hidden id 
    var ids = $(this).closest(".modal-body").find("#ids").val();
    //finding tr with same id and then update the td
    $("table").find("tr[id='" + ids + "']").find("td[data-target='Timer_1']").text(input_val);
    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
  <h2>Ajax</h2>
  <p>Update Timer</p>
  <table class="table">

    <tr id="1">
      <th>Timer 1</th>
      <td data-target="Timer_1"> Something</td>
      <th>
        <a href="#" data-role="update" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="1">Update</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <th>Timer 1</th>
      <td data-target="Timer_1"> Something123</td>
      <th>
        <a href="#" data-role="update" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="2">Update</a>
      </th>
    </tr>


  </table>
  <div class="text-center"></div>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Timer 1</label>
          <input type="hidden" id="ids" class="form-control">
          <input type="text" id="Timer_1" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a href="#" id="save" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Update</a>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks alot. I am able to showcase mySQL values onto the text field from the example . But when I try to update mySQL table it does not get updated. What am I doing wrong? I have updated my code in question under "Edit".

Comment: This `$_POST['ID']` should be `$_POST['ids']` because you have passed `ids` as parameter in ajax call not `ID`

Comment: Thank you that is what was missing :)